# Initialization from incompatible pointer type for multi argument functions in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to declare a function to use with a parameterized array in `*builtin_func[]`, however one of the functions takes in two arguments instead of one (`sh_redirection`).

```
int sh_cd(char **args);
int sh_exit(char **args);
int sh_path(char **args);
int sh_redirection(char **args, int idx);

char ERROR_MESSAGE[128] = "An error has occurred\n";
extern char **environ;

/*
  List of builtin commands, followed by their corresponding functions.
 */
char *builtin_str[] = {
  "cd",
  "path",
  "exit",
   ">"
};

int (*builtin_func[]) (char **) = {
  &sh_cd,
  &sh_path,
  &sh_exit,
  &sh_redirection
};
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
error: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
   &sh_redirection
```

I tried changing the `*builtin_func` to

```
int (*builtin_func[]) (char **, int) = {
&sh_cd,
&sh_path,
&sh_exit,
&sh_redirection
};
```

Looking for a more elegant way to parameterize this

Comment: How would you know how to call that function? You could add a union holding different types of functions and enclose that in a struct that contains a field selecting the correct function.

Comment: How do you use these? Is the char** passing along the string from `builtin_str`? Why must it do that, can't that string be known by the function? That is, `sh_cd` knows it should use `"cd"` etc.

Comment: It cannot be done elegantly. Basically you want to put two incompatible types into a single type. The language will make it difficult and ugly and you should be thankful for that.

Comment: @tstanisl I can very likely be done elegantly if taking one step back from the C language implementation details to look at the program design and purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The declaration part is easy to solve with an explicit cast:

```
typedef int cmd_func(char**);
int (*builtin_func[]) (char**) = {
  &sh_cd,
  &sh_path,
  &sh_exit,
  (cmd_func *)& sh_redirection
};
```

This kind of cast is common in C when you have to store function pointers in structs. Simply the hard part is now to correctly use the function pointer, meaning to pass the expected number of parameters to each function...

Comment: consider `int (*builtin_func[]) (char**)` -> `cmd_func *builtin_func[]`

Answer (score 0):

This is a alternative answer to the better [other one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75589783/4989451).

Currently C allows declaring function types without a prototype, the types list of arguments. So you can make:

```
int (*builtin_func[]) () = {
&sh_cd,
&sh_path,
&sh_exit,
&sh_redirection
};
```

Big disadvantage is that you loose any type checking for parameters.

Moreover there is other more subtle and quite dangerous issue. When calling the function via such pointer type, one must be aware that the call parameters undergo [default argument promotions](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p6) which changes types of some parameters. Like `char` is promoted to `int` or `float` to `double`.

As result you cannot use functions taking `char`, `float`, etc parameters to initialize entries in `builtin_func`. The compiler *may* warn you but it may not.